# How do corrections work in the stock market? Why is the stock market down this week?

Tags: stocks

In spite of positive news, the stock market is bearish and it seems it will keep going down.

Comment: Many other people are wondering why the S&P 500 is up 16% over the last year despite covid shutting down much of the economy.

Comment: Given the current answer actually covers pretty well why this is unanswerable, maybe this question is valuable to the site and worth re-opening?

Answer (score 3):

There is no actual answer, beyond the obvious supply & demand one, that people controlling a lot of money that could be used to buy stocks decided to do something else with it, and/or people that had stocks decided they wanted cash.

The stock market is really not predictable.  When you hear some pundit on the news saying that the market rose/fell because of X, they are just using hindsight and guessing.  If they could predict the market's response to X, they would have already made a large enough fortune and would not need their TV jobs.